# How to send data and get data from tcp/ip port in C,C++ both on Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, c, tcp, port

I am to write a cross platform program for windows and linux ::
    A Java program will send data to a tcp/ip port and there will be a C/C++ program which will continuously listen from that tcp/ip port when it gets some data it will do some works and send the result data to another tcp/ip port from which now the Java program will read the data and do some actions.
    I am more worried about the C/C++ portion. Can you please help with any detail or useful link or sample code ?

Comment: "I want to write programs that communicate via TCP/IP" doesn't make for a useful question.  What specifically are you having trouble with?  What have you tried?

Comment: i want to read data from and send data to tcp/ip port in C,C++ .I am looking for how i can do that ?

Comment: Hint:  What you want is generally related to something called "sockets".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of networking APIs/libraries and event notifications mechanisms. Since I assume you are new to C++ and don't really want to deal with platform-specific functionality in order to squeeze microseconds from your implementation and/or write different code for different platforms, I think your best bet is to use [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html) - a cross-platform C++ library for network and low-level I/O programming. It has a very good documentation, tons of examples, and is pretty easy to use in general. It will work on many platforms w/o a need to change a single line of code in your application. It has its pitfalls, but they are not very significant unless you are doing something extremely complicated that has a lot of strict requirements for performance, memory usage, latency, throughput or all of the above.

Just in case I am not right in my assumptions, there are a lot of alternatives. Some of them are:

- [libevent](http://libevent.org/) - a mechanism to execute a callback function when a specific event occurs on a file descriptor or after a timeout has been reached
- [epoll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll) - a scalable I/O event notification mechanism for Linux
- [kqueue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) - a scalable event notification interface introduced in FreeBSD 4.1[1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html), also supported in NetBSD, OpenBSD, DragonflyBSD, and Mac OS X.
- [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)
- [Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) API (those guys always re-invent the wheel).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html) for C++ cross platform networking and [google protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) for specifying the cross platform/cross language protocol.

Use boost::asio for sending/receiving bytes of data and google protocol buffers to turn those bytes into something useful(ints, strings, etc).